# UWP - make ListView's sticky group header not cover the first visible Item

Tags: c#, uwp

When the `AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled` property value is `True` on the ListView's ItemsStackPanel, the group header (*ListViewHeaderItem*) at the top is always covering the first visible ListViewItem.

And in the situations when the group header's height is greater than the item's height, the item is being completely hidden from view beneath the group header. For some reason *ItemsStackPanel.FirstVisibleIndex* reports the hidden item as visible.

**Is it possible to make the sticky group header background transparent** so that the first ListViewItem is <s>truly</s> fully visible? Editing the `HeaderContainerStyle` style has had no effect on that.

[image: sticky group header occupies all the width available]

**UPD: added a screenshot from the Windows Universal samples**

[image: uwp listview sample]

Comment: No, the group header normally doesn't cover the first item.

Comment: Please suggest some code because this isn't the default behavior

Comment: @JustinXL, it actually does cover the first *visible* item in the viewport when you scroll it down. Please look at XamlListView/Simple ListView Sample from Windows Universal samples. The top (sticky) header is always there no matter what the scroll position is. I just need to make the header transparent. In the picture above the horizontal line is removed from the template. That's why it doesn't look like a header. But it's the same sticky header as the one in the sample.

Comment: @TóthTibor, the default sticky headers' behavior in UWP is to exclusively occupy the upper part of the viewport. And since the sticky header is stretched horizontally, it does always take the full width of the listview even when the actual payload (header text) is relatively short. I'm sure that's redundant in some scenarios. Look at WhatsApp sticky headers in messages. Their sticky header is compact and doesn't take the full width of the screen.