# How to make UWP listview grouped headers semi-transparent

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In xaml, I'm using GroupStyle's HeaderTemplate to implement my headers, and I tried setting every possible parent component's background to semi-transparent (using solidcolorbrush with opacity 0.5) but to no avail. I even tried copying the default style for listviewheaderitem in generic.xaml to page resources and modified the background (and its Template's background) but that didn't work either.

My headers are set sticky, and I hope when I scroll up my listview items I can still see them in an obscure manner through the headers. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I found the similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613026/uwp-make-listviews-sticky-group-header-not-cover-the-first-visible-item). And it looks could not be approached.

Comment: yeah, I saw this one earlier, Seems hopeless